# Prove that there do not exist natural $n$ such that $(1+i)^n=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove that there do not exist natural $n$ such that $(1+i)^n=1$.

I try to prove with the binomial and proving by induction but it isn't working

[image: try to proove]

Maybe there is another way to prove and I'm not thinking in the right way.

Comment: In problems of complex multiplication (like exponentiation), polar form is often much easier to deal with.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. We have written some advice on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  In particular, please include the source and motivation of the problem. There is also an issue with the post that the claim is false - the integer $n = 0$ works. It is not clear why it is not phrased as "there is no positive integer $n$ such that $(1+i)^n = 1$."

Comment: I wrote a comment on the post that i meant "natural number" and not "integer number" but someone delete the comment so you can't see that and i don't know how to edit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$|(1+i)^n|=|(1+i)|^n=(\sqrt{2})^{n}.$$
What may we conclude about the equation $(1+i)^n=1$?

Comment: But isn't $(1+i)^0=1$? 0 is an integer...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That is not denied by this, is it?

Comment: @drhab That $n=0$ solves the given equation is perhaps murkier in the answers other than mine.

Comment: My hint is a general remark for ANY integer $n$.

Comment: It's okay because i made a mistake. I wanted to write "natural number" and not "integer number" so this solution is perfect for my question and thank you.

Answer (score 7):

$$(1+i)^0=1$$

> However, it is quite simple to show that 0 is the *only* integer exponent that solves the equation, e.g. by considering the polar form; the magnitude of $(1+i)^n$ is $\sqrt2^n$, which is 1 only for $n=0$.

Comment: But I don't think you **need** polar forms to get $|zw|=|z||w|$ or $|z^n|=|z|^n$.

Comment: @bof I have added that in.

Answer (score 3):

Shortcut:

If indeed $z^n=1$ then also $|z|^n=|z^n|=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Take modulus. $1=|(1+i)^{n}|=(\sqrt 2)^{n}$ which is impossible except when $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $n$ a positive integer.

Compute $(1+i)^1=1+i; (1+i)^2=2i; (1+i)^3=2(i-1); (1+i)^4=-4$

You can then easily express $(1+i)^{4n+r}: 0\le r\le3$ as one of four simple expressions which depend on $r$, and this will extend to negative $n$ too. The only real values occur for $r=0$.